# Netlogo: Concatenate elements of neighbour's list in an agent's list

Tags: list, concatenation, netlogo

Each agent has a list called m-list. Every agent has a different number of neighbours (called flockmates). I want every agent to add neighbour's m-list into his own m-list.

I am not able to remove the excessive list brackets and get list elements to put them one by one in the list. Also, to note, the length of m-list varies with agents.

```
ask turtles [
  set flockmates (other turtles) in-radius communication-radius 
 ;neighbours within a given radius
 set m-list fput map [ i ->  [m-list] of i ] sort flockmates m-list
 show m-list
 ]

  ;I also tried this:
 show sentence m-list map [ i -> [m-list] of i ] sort flockmates

   if my m-list = [x y z]
   and my two neighbours is [a b c d] and [s t] then,
   m-list should be [ x y z a b c d s t]
   and I receive something like: [[[a b c d] [x y z]] [s t]] :/
```

Comment: If you stick with lists, you probably want some combination of `reduce` and `sentence`. But lists will mean you have duplicate members. But keeping track of flockmates sounds more like an agentset mechanism. Can you just clarify why you are using lists rather than agentsets as that will affect how to answer.

Comment: Hi, I want every agent know who the neighbours are connected to. I am thinking in C, so, I thought of putting it all in an array (here list) and then picking any nodes, shortest path to me(an agent).

I basically want to know, by communication/message passing, that who is connected to whom, so that I can compute the shortest path to a node. I do not want the observer to give agents the link, but agents to compute 'who is connected to whom' via neighours and neighbours' neighbours.. and so on

Comment: Have you looked at the network extension for NetLogo? There is no need to write a procedure to calculate shortest paths. But, if you were to write one and therefore needed to keep track of neighbourhoods of different sizes, then agentsets is what you need rather than lists.